# Using an ArrayList as a datasource in an ephemeral Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a REST provider with Spring Boot. It is ephemeral by design i.e. the data can be lost when the application is killed. So, I decided to use an `ArrayList` to make CRUD operations on: it should be like a singleton -created with the app and used along the way.

I have this rest controller, with the service layer autowired:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceInterface myService;

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<MyEntity> retrieveAll() {
        return myService.getAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public MyEntity create(@RequestBody MyEntity entity) {
        return myService.insert(entity);
    }
}
```

and the `MyService` implementing `MyServiceInterface` is as follows:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface {

    // This is my ArrayList to live while the Spring Boot app runs
    private List<MyEntity> myList = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();

    @Override
    public MyEntity insert(MyEntity entity) {
        this.myList.add(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyEntity> getAll() {
        return this.myList;
    }
}
```

So, is it fine to use a humble private `myList` object in the serive class as shown above, or should I take a different approach (inject that `myList` after assigning it as a `@Bean`, add `@Configuration` or whatsoever Spring stuff)?

**EDIT:**  Not to sail away from my concern, my primary point is not discussing databases instead of lists, but how to declare a variable used by multiple methods of a Spring Bean.

Comment: Forgot to state that, just added to question: any kind of database (in-memo, rdbms, so on) is not allowed

Comment: isn't your list an in memory list? you also do not want to use an array list because it's not thread safe

Comment: Apart from the thread-safety (which is a good point of yours), I mean third party in-memory data grid solutions.

Comment: Unless you need to share data across multiple instances of your program, I think any kind of data grid is overkill.  Data structures that just need to exist ephemerally inside a single process are a great use of Python's build in data structures.  You can deal with the thread safety without bringing in complexity of some sort of data grid module. - if you ARE talking about sharing across processes, then Redis is a great solution.  Very simple to use.  But it requires external setup.  Not at all necessary for a single process that doesn't need to preserve it's data across restarts.

Comment: Your requirement seems contradictory; not having an in-memory database yet storing everything in a data structure like ArrayList sounds like you're allowed an in-memory database, just with the catch that you have to do *all* of the work.  You're probably not going to get the answer you want from this unless you clarify why the in-memory databases are strictly forbidden to begin with.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Steve Nope, indeed, my point was the declaration type of `myList` as a singleton during the lifetime of a Spring Boot application. But, I just needed to edit and add that *no-db* clause it as it was about to lose focus.

Comment: ah, ok.  well, it doesn't matter much how your list comes into existence.  No need to fancy it up with spring injection unless there's some external reason to do that, like mocking for testing or something like that.  whatever gets it done is probably fine. 

In terms of thread safety, it depends on how efficient you need to be.  A basic solution is that you can turn many non-thread-safe java classes into thread safe ones with something like this:

List newList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

Comment: In short, what you have here seems fine until you start talking about a need for better performance, in which case how this "database" will be used becomes important.  - If all you need to do is add items and return the whole list, this is just fine.

Comment: Saw your latest changes.  If you're considering declaring the list in some other way, I'd simply ask "why?".  From what you have said so far, I see nothing to be gained. - dependency injection just gives you flexibility...a way to change your code's logic without changing your code.

Comment: If there were any reasons for not to do so: any kind of side effects, gains, conventions etc. Your previous *No need to fancy it up* was sorta the word I sought for.

Comment: yip. In general, if you don't know why to make something more complex, don't.